# Can a polarized light be reflected?

Tags: visible-light, reflection, polarization

First of all, this question is NOT about what happens to an unpolarized light when it is reflected by a surface. This question is already well answered by the web and is not my current concern.

I am asking **what is happening when an already polarized light is being reflected**. Does the polarization not change, does it become partially polarized, does it become unpolarized completely, or does it not get reflected at all? And what happens in the case of a partially polarized light? Lastly, if we scale it up with a polarized light beam being reflected by multiple surfaces, what can I expect at the end?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For perpendicular incidence polarisation is not relevant. For incidence at an angle, the reflection coefficients are different. In many cases there is an angle, known as the Brewster angle, for which only one polarisation is reflected. The angle and polarisation dependent, complex valued Fresnel coefficients describe this. Look for Fresnel equations.